# Is it possible to get bitcoin-cli without having to build all bitcoin source?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'd like to use the bitcoin client to examine some of the inner workings of bitcoin-qt (non-invasively, using gets and lists mostly). Is it possible to do this alongside the standard executable? I don't really want to download and build everything from source.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. `bitcoin-cli` is distributed alongside `bitcoin-qt`. What do you mean by examing Bitcoin using gets and lists?

Comment: I'm running bitcoin core but I haven't built it, just dowloaded the executable. I want to use bitcoin-cli to send commands such as getinfo, listtransactions, getbalance, etc. Possibly I can do that through bitcoin core's UI. Currently I'm waiting for it to start up on my system.

Comment: This is a bit difficult with the bitcoin-cli but check out some libraries like [this](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) which constructs transactions and signs them or [toshi](https://github.com/coinbase/toshi) which was put out by coinbase and offers a lot more customization.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Go to Bitcoin-Qt -> Help -> Debug Window.

Help -> Command Line Options gives a list of all options.

Answer (score 1):

*TL;DR: Yes, "make ./src/bitcoin-cli".*

---

The full procedure (with bitcoin-0.11.0, you may want to download a newer version if any):

```
cd ~/
wget https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.11.0/bitcoin-0.11.0.tar.gz
sha256sum bitcoin-0.11.0.tar.gz | grep 51ba1756addfa71567559e3f22331c1d908a63571891287689fff7113035d09f
tar xfz bitcoin-0.11.0.tar.gz
cd bitcoin-0.11.0
./configure --enable-hardening --disable-wallet --disable-upnp-default --without-miniupnpc
make ./src/bitcoin-cli
```

Check that everything is fine:

```
./src/bitcoin-cli --help
```

Comment: This answer seems to miss the point as the asker states he does ***not*** want to build from the source.